# How do I tighten these table columns?

Tags: tables, columns

I would like for columns A1, A3 and B1 to be more like column B3, which doesn't have any cell padding on the side facing out of its group.

[image: Table with less than tight columns]

Can I achieve that? The code I have right now looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table*}\centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lccccccc@{}}\toprule
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{A} & \phantom{abc}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{B}\\ \cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-8}
      & 1 & 2 & 3 && 1 & 2 & 3\\
      \midrule
      C     &       0.60  &       0.951 &       0.245         & &       1.151         &       1.563         &       0.586         \\
                  &     (0.262)         &     (0.364)         &     (0.310)         & &     (0.620)         &     (0.905)         &     (0.696)         \\
      \midrule
      \(N\)       &      919629         &      468093         &      451536         & &      186271         &       94771         &       91500         \\

      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your columns in "A" parts are the same as in "B" parts of table. do you like to remove empty column  between this two parts?

Comment: @Zarko No, the columns look differnt. As you can see the `\cmidrule` extends further to right in the A3 column than in the B3 column. If removing the empty column would help resolve my issue, then I am open to that.

Comment: yes, but this barely caught sight of it. the simple solution is remove all `@{}` in your table. however, see answers below for more "sophisticated" solutions :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to getting rid of the empty column, I'd line up the numbers on their decimal markers, say, using the tools of the `dcolumn` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{6}{d{2.4}} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{B}\\ \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
& \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} \\
\midrule
C & 0.60    & 0.951   & 0.245   & 1.151   & 1.563   & 0.586   \\
  & (0.262) & (0.364) & (0.310) & (0.620) & (0.905) & (0.696) \\
\midrule
$N$ & \mc{919629} & \mc{468093} & \mc{451536} & \mc{186271} &  \mc{94771} &  \mc{91500} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! There wouldn't be some way to increase the space between A3 and B1 without adding a phantom column inbetween them?

Comment: @FredrikP - In my experience, tables with noticeably different amounts of inter-column whitespace quickly risk looking either unbalanced or, worse, amateurish. Thus, if you want to increase the space between A3 and B1, you should probably widen the other inter-column spaces as well. E.g., change `\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{6}{d{2.4}} @{}}` to `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} \begin{tabular*}{0.9\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{6}{d{2.4}} }`. (Of course, change `\end{tabular}` to `\end{tabular*}` as well.) Feel free to adjust the overall width (`0.9\textwidth`) to suit your taste.

Comment: Albeit it might be ill-advised, is there some way to do it? To be clear, I would like to both the space between the first and second columns and the space between the fourth and fifth column. I think that would look balanced. It’s just that I can’t figure out how to increase the second space without an extra column.

Answer (score 6):

i would write your table slightly different:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}% added

\begin{document}
  \begin{table*}\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l *{6}{S[input-symbols = ( ),
                          table-space-text-pre={(},
                          table-space-text-post={)},
                          table-format=1.3]} }% changed
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{A}                         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{B}                         \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
        & {1}           & {2}           & {3}           & {1}           & {2}           & {3}           \\
    \midrule
C       &  0.60         &  0.951        &  0.245        &  1.151        &  1.563        &  0.586        \\
        & (0.262)       & (0.364)       & (0.310)       & (0.620)       & (0.905)       & (0.696)       \\
  \midrule
\(N\)   & \num{919629}  & \num{468093}  & \num{451536}  & \num{186271}  & \num{94771}   & \num{91500}   \\ %changed
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
  \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

or eventualy:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table*}\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l *{3}{S[input-symbols = ( ),
                          table-space-text-pre={(},
                          table-space-text-post={)},
                          table-format=1.3]}
                    c
                   *{3}{S[input-symbols = ( ),
                          table-space-text-pre={(},
                          table-space-text-post={)},
                          table-format=1.3]} }
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{A}                         && \multicolumn{3}{c}{B}                        \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-8}
        & {1}           & {2}           & {3}           && {1}          & {2}           & {3}           \\
    \midrule
C       &  0.60         &  0.951        &  0.245        &&  1.151       &  1.563        &  0.586        \\
        & (0.262)       & (0.364)       & (0.310)       && (0.620)      & (0.905)       & (0.696)       \\
  \midrule
\(N\)   & \num{919629}  & \num{468093}  & \num{451536}  && \num{186271} & \num{94771}   & \num{91500}   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
  \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

(difference is in inserted empty column which add more space between table part A and B.

Comment: I like that you managed to add space between the columns without the extra column, but your solution causes the line below B not to reach all the way out to the right-hand side of the table.

Comment: @FredrikP, `lines below A and B are deliberately select to be equal and slightly shorter than width of the columns below them. if you not liked this, then remove . increasing space between A and B parts without introduce new column (which is the simplest way) is not trivial, since extending space might introduce asymmetry in columns width.  i will not do this.

Answer (score 4):

Use `(lr)` combinations with your `\cmidrule`s and remove `\phantom{abc}`, it adds too much space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table*}\centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lccccccc@{}}
        \toprule
                                             &    \multicolumn{3}{c}{A}    &  &    \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{B}    \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){6-8} &    1    &    2    &    3    &  &    1    &    2    &    3    \\ \midrule
        C                                    &  0.60   &  0.951  &  0.245  &  &  1.151  &  1.563  &  0.586  \\
                                             & (0.262) & (0.364) & (0.310) &  & (0.620) & (0.905) & (0.696) \\ \midrule
        \(N\)                                & 919629  & 468093  & 451536  &  & 186271  &  94771  &  91500  \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Very nice! This solves it. I awarded the answer to @Mico simply b/c of posting first.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table*}\centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\hskip\tabcolsep}@{}ccc@{}c@{\hskip\tabcolsep}@{}ccc@{}}\toprule
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{A} & \phantom{abc}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{B}\\ \cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-8}
      & 1 & 2 & 3 && 1 & 2 & 3\\
      \midrule
      C     &       0.60  &       0.951 &       0.245 & &       1.151 &       1.563   &       0.586    \\
            &     (0.262) &     (0.364) &     (0.310) & &     (0.620) &     (0.905)   &     (0.696)    \\
      \midrule
      \(N\) &      919629 &      468093 &      451536 & &      186271 &       94771   &       91500    \\

      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! This solves it. I awarded the answer to @Mico simply b/c of posting first.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by changing

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccccccc@{}}
```

to

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}ccc@{}c@{}ccc@{}}
```

Comment: This also removes the right `tabcolsep` of the first column and leads to a very small distance between 'N' and '919629'.